# Django view DateField Format headache

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Help would be appreciated. Whatever i search for I find everything else but what I need it seems. wwwaaah....

I have a DateField on my template that i need to get user specified date for an API i am building. My trouble is I need it in a specific format. I have googled and trying various params but cant get to work. Django's DateField default format is yyyy-mm-dd, but due to how our API works I need yyyy/mm/dd.

**specs:**
-django1.5
-python27

*What works....*

**views.py**

```
class AddForm(forms.Form):
    new_timestamp = forms.DateField(required=False)

class TimeView(View):

    def post(self, request)

        time_content = AddForm(request.POST)
        content['client_time'] = time_content

        if time_content.is_valid():
            new_timestamp = time_content.cleaned_data["new_timestamp"]

        ...
        ...blah blah
```

**template:**

```
<div id="div_date_section">Date: <input type="text" name="new_timestamp"> YYYY/MM/DD </div>
```

Gives me the following output (*captured in my debug logs*):

```
2016-11-10 23:46:48,520: DEBUG: views.py:296  timestamp: 2016-01-01 00:00:00-08:00
2016-11-10 23:46:48,520: DEBUG: views.py:297  timestamp type: <type 'datetime.datetime'>
```

---

What I would like is a string formatted as: **2016/01/01**.

I have tried various methods to no effect. As mentioned I have been googling for hours, and one of thing i found was as follows, however this makes my code not work. I get absolutely no error to log or console, my code just breaks complaining about something unrelated down a few lines of code later on in my code.

```
new_timestamp = forms.DateField(widget=forms.widgets.DateInput(format="%Y/%m/%d"),required=False)
```

Can anyone advise please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should show this supposedly unrelated error.

Comment: Also, it's not clear from your question: are you talking about the format you input into the form, it the format you get out?

Comment: Hi Daniel. sorry for that, I am referring to the format being passed into the form user input. if i pretend to be the user and punch in 2016/01/01 you can see from my debug log that 2016-01-01 format is being passed through via the default DateField module.I some how need to override that to this format 2016/01/01 which is not django standard. I didnt paste the error as i didnt want people focusing on it. I have a "if form.is_valid()" block that returns a few dicts. One of them is "sku_found". because the if is valid fails the error shows saying sku_found blah blah...but of course it does....

Comment: I'm sorry, I *can't* see from the debug log that "2016-01-01 format is being passed"; what makes you think that? And exactly what code are you using to produce those log entries, and where?

Comment: ...as the **if is_valid()** fails and thus my sku_found is reference in the return statement as my code under if form.is_valid() fails to do anything. hopefully this makes some sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling for a bit longer, I realized the requirements of what i was trying to do was slightly different. While i still needed to alter what the user entered, I found I could manipulate the DateTime object as such to give me what I needed (which turned out to be epoch format):

```
class AddForm(forms.Form):
    new_timestamp = forms.DateField(required=False)

class TimeView(View):
def post(self, request)

    time_content = AddForm(request.POST)
    content['client_time'] = time_content

    if time_content.is_valid():
        new_timestamp = time_content.cleaned_data["new_timestamp"]

    ...
    ...
        results = some_def(new_timestamp)
    ...
    ...

def some_def:
    ...
    ...
    # the new line that gave me what i needed
    epoch_time = time.mktime(new_timestamp.timetuple())
    ...
    ...
    return epoch_time
```

I realize there is not enough context here but hopefully this is clear enough how to pass user input via DateField on a template and convert. This example is for converting something like 2016-01-01 to epoch time format.

just a note, to avoid my initial problem the default DateField format is yyyy-mm-dd and if you use yyyy/mm/dd without any widgets or format manipulation trying so with .is_valid() will fail.